# Where do I ask about software faults?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I currently have an issue with my Bose QC35 Bluetooth headphones. I am not sure if it’s hardware or software, but I think it’s software.

I don’t think it should go on Stack Overflow as it hasn’t to do with programming, nor should it go on Ask Different even though my media devices are Apple based.

What site should I ask such problem on? The issue is to do with connectivity.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ might be an appropriate place to ask.

Comment: _@iProgram_ _"nor should it go on Ask Different"_  Can you elaborate why you think so please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It’s because the problem was with my Bose headphones, rather than my Apple devices.

Comment: There's no site for gadgets or consumer electronics like that. For some reason it has just never worked out

Comment: Maybe people from chat can help to sort that out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309294/where-do-i-ask-about-software-faults?noredirect=1#comment1008162_309294 But I'm afraid there's no appropriate site.

Comment: Perhaps you would be better contacting your headphone provider and claim your warranty.

Comment: I doubt there's much user-serviceable on a pair of Bluetooth headphones. Check the company's website. Read the manual. Shouldn't take long for you to pitch them in the trashbasket and buy a new pair.